# Google Chrome returning 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: google-chrome, http-status-code-503

I have been having an issue lately with Google Chrome. Some sites, seems to be completely random, are returning a 503 Service Unavailable error message. The last one I received was from my hosting provider when trying to access my CPanel. I can access the same URL completely fine in Firefox or IE. It seems to be isolated to Chrome.

I have tried the following:

1. Disabled all extensions
2. Logged in/out of my Google account
3. Cleared all cache and history

So far, nothing seems to correct the issue. It's becoming more and more aggravating from what was once a pretty reliable browser.

I am running:

Windows 7 
Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: I love how this was down voted... For what? it's an issue with Google Chrome. If there is a fix, I would love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. Uninstall Chrome with clear personal data option selected
2. Install Chrome again but without admin right (install for your personal
   user)
3. Use Chrome as normal

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same issue. Mostly, it would occur on intranet sites at work, but it happened with a few exterior sites.  Loading in IE Tab would work fine.

**I was able to solve the issue by upgrading to 64-bit Chrome.**  I'm not sure why that fixed it, but I think it had something to do with a conflict between Java and Chrome (It looks like I have both 64bit and 32bit Java installed side-by-side).

Comment: I just tried installing a new release which had a "new_chrome.exe" in it... It looked to be the one installed or updated today. I'll try it for a bit, see how it goes, and get back.